# How to highlight all occurrences of a search without moving the cursor?

Tags: search

> How to highlight all occurrences of a search without moving the cursor?

I want to highlight all occurrences of a word in the neighbourhood of the cursor without moving the cursor.

Currently, if I use `*` or `#` to highlight all occurrences of the word under the cursor, then I have to press `N` to get back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have run into the same problem before and spent some time to figure it out. Here is my answer. It works great.

```
nnoremap <Space>* <Cmd>let @/='\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'<bar>set hlsearch<CR>
```

`/` is a register which stores search pattern. We use `let` command to set it to the pattern you want to search and set hightlight to ensure it will be hightlighted.

Oh, the above only works in `neovim`. If you are using normal `vim`, it should be like this:

```
nnoremap <silent><Space>* :let @/='\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'<bar>set hlsearch<CR>
```

Comment: How do you run the macro in `vim`? Pressing `<Space>*` works just like pressing `*`.  What does `<bar>` means? `:help <bar>` doesn't return anything useful. Are you using register `/` because it's associated with the search command `/`, or could you use any register name?

Comment: @Shuzheng Sorry, I didn't test it on `vim`. It should work now after I changed `<Silent>` to `<silent>`.

Comment: @Shuzheng `<Bar>` is `|`, which is used to run multiple commands at one time. Try `:echo 123 | echo 789<CR>` and see the result. See `:h map_bar` for the reason I use `<bar>` insteand of `|` here.

Comment: @Shuzheng Yes, I use regitster `/` because it is for search pattern. Other registers have different meanings: `+` for system clipboard, `%` for the name of the current file, `:` for the most recent excuted command-line, and so on. (see `:h registers`)  We can get or set the value of a register by prepending `@` to it. Try `:echo @%<CR>`. See `:h 41.3` for more information about expressions in `Vim`.

Comment: @sdp Welcome to [vi.se]! Great first answer

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, one uses a mapping like

```
nnoremap * *N
```

Using matches and cursorhold has also been done

Comment: Thanks, I now use the normal mapping `nnoremap <leader>* *N`, and it works great! Do you also know a simple command for highlighting all words by entering the word? I would like something like `nnormal <leader>/ /N`, but what doesn't work.

Comment: You mean just highlighting all the matches of a search? For that you would need to use match, like in Matt’s answer

Comment: But Matt expands `<cword>`. I want to enter the search string. What I want is `/` without it moving the cursor - is that possible?

Comment: You could probably do it with a custom command, sure

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>h :execute 'match Search /\V'..escape(expand('<cword>'), '\/')..'/'<CR>
```

But note that you'll need `:match none` to switch it off.